# OSM2PO V5.1 - Routing from mid line not working with Ovl routers

Tags: routing, osm2po

I am using osm2po v5.1.0

I have combined 6 country pbf extracts as such:

```
java -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar prefix=sk cmd=tj slovakia-latest.osm.pbf    
java -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar prefix=at cmd=tj austria-latest.osm.pbf    
java -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar prefix=cz cmd=tj czech-republic-latest.osm.pbf    
java -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar prefix=hu cmd=tj hungary-latest.osm.pbf    
java -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar prefix=pl cmd=tj poland-latest.osm.pbf    
java -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar prefix=ua cmd=tj ukraine-latest.osm.pbf    
java -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar prefix=slovakia-plus sk at cz hu pl ua cmd=m    
java -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar prefix=slovakia-plus cmd=sg
```

I have uncommented all these Ovl routes:

```
router.4.class=de.cm.osm2po.routing.OvlRouter
router.5.class=de.cm.osm2po.routing.OvlEdgeRouter
router.6.class=de.cm.osm2po.routing.OvlPoiRouter
```

I have used this URL to try and route starting away from a vertex (mid-line), using routerClassID=4:

> http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService?format=geojson&routerClassId=4&cmd=fr&source=48.92456,20.85100&target=48.92439,20.69805&findShortestPath=false&ignoreRestrictions=false&ignoreOneWays=false&heuristicFactor=0.0&maxCost=0.0&debugExpansion=false&key=Key&value=Value&tsp=

However, my results look exactly the same as using routerClassID=0 (DefaultRouter)

The end points of the routes are the same, lying on a vertex:
[image]

Am I missing a configuration? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here:

http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService?format=geojson&routerId=4&cmd=fr&source=48.92456,20.85100&target=48.92439,20.69805&findShortestPath=false&ignoreRestrictions=false&ignoreOneWays=false&heuristicFactor=0.0

The crucial param is `routerId` instead of `routerClassId`.
However, I remember that I used the latter somewhere in the past but now cannot find it in my history or documentation anymore.
Can you show me the location where you have it from?

Comment: I have been using osm2po on and off for many years now. I must have had an old URL that I used as a template, containing 'routerClassId' instead of the newer 'routerIDd'. Perhaps from version osm2po-4.5.25 or earlier? If you do a search in gis.stackexchange for 'routerClassId' you can find it hanging around. Many thanks for your quick response.